# Is there a way to ban a function from a certain interface in eslint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Ideally for javascript but if it can only work with typescript that is also an acceptable answer. Let's say we have the following function definition:

```js
// File A.ts
interface SomeReturn {
  badFunc: () => void;
}

export const someGenerator = (): SomeReturn => {
  return {
    badFunc: () => {
      throw new Error('badFunc');
    },
  };
};
```

Then it gets called in file B like so:

```js
// File B.ts
import { someGenerator } from 'A.ts';

const { badFunc } = someGenerator();

// This is where I would want eslint to warn me that badFunc is being used
badFunc();
```

I've tried using `eslint-plugin-ban` which works as long as the returned object from the generator is assigned to a variable whose name I can predict, but A) I can't always predict how people will name their objects, and B) People like destructuring returns immediately.

Assume that `A.ts` is a library that I can't easily modify.

Comment: What about leveraging typescript instead of relying on eslint? You can make a custom definition for the library?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did look into tslint but I couldn't figure out a way there either. I don't control the library, I can't change it, but I would like to ban exactly two methods from the object returned from a function in the library from my project.